# How to add new relationship (foreign index) to existing Code First domain class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have an existing Code First class:

```
public class Asset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public List<Registration> Registration { get; set; }
    ...
    public long AssetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

However, we'd now like to track additional (asset type) information related to the existing Asset class:

```
public class AssetInfo
{
    public int AssetInfoId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best method of modifying this relationship to link the two tables?

I had thought a two step process of first adding in the relationship changes in code and doing a migration followed by an updated initialization/seed method to correct the index values might be the best way - but there were issues. 
Adding a relationship between the two will allow me to 'add-migration' the database, albeit by modifying the base migration setting for AssetInfoId to (nullable: true). I thought then I could then use the Configuration/Seed function to correct the index values - but I'm having issues because AssetInfoId could not be set to 'null' value.

Comment: Try adding an explicit FK to Assest that is nullable: `public int? AssetInfoId { get; set; }` or use a fluent configuration Asset HasOptional( a => a.AssetInfo).WithRequired(a => a.Asset).

Comment: @SteveGreene I did exactly the first suggestion (FK that is nullable) and I was able to link the two tables! I then followed it up with a Configuraiton/Seed operation to adjust the index value. If you'd like to write propose the answer, I can acknowledge it. Thanks.